# Subtle differences between regex matching in SpecFlow method binding

Tags: c#, regex, specflow

I would like to define these two step bindings for two separate methods:

```
Given I remember {word} as {key}
And I remember that {key} is {word}
```

The problem is that the bindings I have so far are:

```
[Given(@"I remember (.*) as (.*)")]
[Given(@"I remember that (.*) is (.*)")]
```

These, of course, evaluate as duplicates because the `(.*)` in the first binding overrides the second binding.

How can I specify the regex to differentiate these bindings? Specifically, so the inclusion of `that` causes the second binding to match, whereas the omission of `that` matches the first.

Comment: Can you elaborate, please?

Comment: Disclaimer: I dont know about specflow - but why should both things clash? They differ in `is` and `as` - patternwise

Comment: How do you know it's bad?

Comment: The first (.*) will match anything after the ‘that’ and including the ‘that’.

Comment: @MattW Have you tried it? In your example as/is should prevent it unless you craft your word/key in a specific way

Comment: Yes, I have. That’s why I’m posting. The specflow plugin highlights it as duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trial and error has produced this working solution...

This feature step

```
Given I remember {word} as {key}
```

matches this method attribute

```
[Given(@"I remember (?!that)(.*) as (.*)")]
```

And this feature step

```
And I remember that {key} is {word}
```

matches this method attribute

```
[Then(@"^I remember that (.*) is equal to (.*)$")]
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to make sure that the first part before any pattern is different for the fist and following clauses.
E.g.

> Given I remember {word} as {key}
>
> And I `also` remember that {key} is {word}

This way there is no common part before the first pattern.

Comment: Me too, I just want to go beyond that and as regex is so powerful I m hoping there’s a way.

Comment: Powerful? Sure. But, less easy to understand the more complex your expression gets.

Comment: Yeah, I’m not so worried about that right now. Just want to know if it’s possible.